# How to show javadoc in VScode?

Tags: java, linux, visual-studio, ubuntu, javadoc

I'm currently using Ubuntu Linux. When I used to program on windows using eclipse, I could easily open javadoc when I hover over a function or when I press control and click it. Now I'm using VS code, and I can't see javadoc for some reason. When I hover over the function (Math.ceil for example) it shows some empty code that only returns 0 [as in the screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbN7A.png).

I've already installed java extension pack. Any solutions to this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show Javadoc on hover in VS Code in Java Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63295527/how-to-show-javadoc-on-hover-in-vs-code-in-java-project)

Comment: So sorry for late reply. Yeah I've tried that already and it didn't fix the issue. I guess I'm going to use eclipse anyways although it also doesn't show javadoc too. Since I've switched to Linux a lot of stuff are different and I think I've missed up some stuff because I downloaded multiple versions of java. Thanks anyways